# Is there a way to stop reporting on a specific request when locust.io

Tags: locust

I'm writing a locust.io based performance test scenarios. As part of the User journey I had to navigate to a url (which will end with a session/{guid} before getting a cookie for a session, which I can continue to apply within the cookie headers to carry on with other parts of the journey.

Now I want to avoid reporting on the initial url which ends in session/{guid}, as otherwise I'll be hitting different endpoints as the {guid} will keep changing for every single request, as that is a redirect URL that I get from a system.

So, is there a setting that I can use to stop locust.io from reporting on that specific request?

Hope the above question is clear enough in what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, actually, I avoided l.client.post and for that URL request alone I used the python requests api's post method, so locust can't track it :)